# is there a way i can see all my favourited questions in one place

Tags: support, questions

in other words how can i "archive" my favourite QA's

Answer (score 4):

Your [profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/22098/ryuzaki) contains all your starred questions.